# JQuery - slideToggle() is sliding up instead of down

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

can I know what's wrong with my code? slideToggle is sliding up instead of sliding down.

This below is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Uppgift 3</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="dropdown"> </div> 
    <div class="dropdown"> </div>    
    <div class="dropdown"> </div>
    <div class="dropdown"> </div>
    <div class="dropdown"> </div>    
    <div class="dropdown"> </div>    
</div>
</body>
```

This below is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown").click(function () {
        $(this).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

This below is my CSS code:

```
#navigation {
    width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:7%;
    display:block;
}

div.dropdown {
    height:50px;
    width:140px;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    background-color:steelblue;
    margin-left: 12px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I did wrong? It's sliding up for some reason >.< Thanks in advance =) Cheers

Comment: [Fiddle with the code you have provided](http://jsfiddle.net/3CzLr/), add more code if any and then add it in your question...

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. Your elements are visible, so when you call `.slideToggle()` they slide upwards and are hidden. [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/): *Description: Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.*

Comment: billyonecan describes the `slideToggle()` event perfectly. You're expecting the behaviour of the `slideDown` event but this is dependent of having a "parent" div toggling the "child" div downwards. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_down).